# How does HttpSession from javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest work

Tags: java, spring-boot, http

How is a session identified in a javax HttpSession  ?  Let's say I store something in a session. Firstly how long will it stay there. I think I do not enter any timeout. So what will be default. And how is the session identified. Is it by cookie ?  What if I use multiple browsers.  Will there be an own session for every single browser ? So if I use Chrome for 5 minutes and store stuff in the session, then I use IE the session will be empty again ?

Additionally I want to add , it seems if I shutdown the server the session automatically gets deleted, so session stuff seems only to be saved in RAM.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally session are identified with a cookie, so:

1. yes, if you change browser you'll open a new session and you'll lost every data stored in previous session: it's another session!
2. yes, session data are stored in RAM, f it is not explicitly saved (directly or indirectly) in a DB or File or other data storage.

Finally, the default timeout depends on the server used, generally is 30 min. The customization of the timeout depends, again, on the server used. In tomcat/tomee for example you can change this value on application based (in the web.xml a deploy descriptor of java galaxy)